# Weird jquery event bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure if this is actually an event bubbling issue. `event.stopPropagation()` doesn't solve the problem. The scenario is:

1. Click element class 'clickMe' (as many clicks as you want)
2. Then click `li` element. The click event will be executed based on numbers of click on 'clickMe' class.

Below is the snippet of the code:

html:

```
<div class="clickMe">Click Me 1</div>
<div class="clickMe">Click Me 2</div>
<div class="clickMe">Click Me 3</div>
<ul id="test">
    <li><a href="#">Test A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test B</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test C</a></li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    $('.clickMe').live('click', function(e){
        //e.stopPropagation()
        $('li', $('#test')).live('click',function(e){
            //e.stopPropagation()
            alert('ouch')            
        })        
    })
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help or explanation about this issue.

Comment: What do you mean with "will be executed based on numbers of click"? Where do you count them?

Comment: What do you intend to happen ? And why are you attaching a click event handler in the `clickMe` event handler in the first place ?

Comment: "will be executed based on numbers of click" is not what I'm trying to achieve. It's the issue that I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Ah well that's because u add an handler each time you click on .clickMe. So when u click the li button, each handler gets executed. So that's why multiple alerts happen.

Comment: I was actually playing around with codes. The idea is whenever right click is made on 'clickMe', any click on the li will be triggered. And  the snippet is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

You're adding *another* click handler to the `<li>` elements whenever a "click" happens on one of the "clikMe" `<div>` elements. The jQuery code maintains all of those handlers, so after you've clicked "clickMe" a few times, there are several handlers and they'll all be called.

The `.live()` method is not the best way to delegate event handling. Use `.on()` if you're using a new version of jQuery, or at least `.delegate()`.

Answer (score 2):

For every click on `clickMe` you are attaching an event to `#test` that is your li element

> [live](http://jqapi.com/#p=live) attaches an event handler for all elements which match the selector, now and in the future.

Separate both and use [on](http://jqapi.com/#p=on)

```
$('.clickMe').on('click', function(e) {
    //e.stopPropagation()
})
$('li', $('#test')).on('click', function(e) {
    //e.stopPropagation()
    alert('ouch');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/aEkNa/

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var clickme_clicks = 0, clickme_timeout = setTimeout(function(){},0) ;

    $('.clickMe').on('click', function(e){
        clickme_clicks++;        
        clearTimeout( clickme_timeout );
        clickme_timeout = setTimeout(function(){ clickme_clicks = 0; },1000);
    });

     $('li a', $('#test')).on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //if(clickme_clicks == 0) return;
        alert('clicks: ' + clickme_clicks );         
    })  
});​
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he want. "The click event will be executed based on numbers of click on 'clickMe' class." is what's already happening, and he asks why.

Comment: @gl3nn I'll let the OP clarify his needs. I did what it appears he is trying to do.

Comment: He already clarified himself in the comments on his question, I was confused too.

Comment: Thanks man for the code. But like I said before, I don't really need to know about the number of clicks. And yes by separating the event listener solve the issue (like you and the rest of the guys who suggested the solution)

Comment: I still don't know what it is you are trying to do but I am glad it helped get you there.